# Integrable version of the Borel-Cantelli theorem?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

I have taken an introductory course on measure theory where I learned about the Borel-Cantelli theorem but I wonder whether there is a lebesgue integrable version. Given an uncountable collection of independent events $E_{t \in \mathbb{R}_+}$,

$$ \int_0^{\infty} P(E_t) dt <\infty \implies P( E_t\quad i.o. )=0\tag{1}$$

$$ \int_0^{\infty} P(E_t) dt =\infty \implies P( E_t\quad i.o. )=1\tag{2}$$

**Note**: i.o. here means infinitely often. I'd like to add that this question is motivated by a problem I encountered in statistical physics.

Comment: As written, this must be false: for example, let all $E_t$ be the same event, with probability $1/2$. Then $P(E_t \, i.o.)=P(E_1)=1/2$. You would need to add some condition of independence, or decay of correlations, or the like...

Comment: @JamesMartin Ok. I clarified the question. Is the statement now true?

Comment: "Clarified" as in "changed" :) Now it is implied by the normal Borel-Cantelli lemma, since you can find a countable sequence $t_k$ such that $\sum P(E_{t_k})=\infty$.

Comment: @JamesMartin I think I now have both cases of the Borel-Cantelli theorem, and this result is more general than what I wanted earlier. Would you agree?

Comment: Both of these now look wrong. For the second, aren't we back where we started? Without some condition of independence, or correlation decay, this one must be doomed. For the first, let $E_t$ be independent with $P(E_t)=1$ if $t$ is an integer, and $P(E_t)=0$ otherwise. Then the integral is _zero_, but from the standard B-C lemma, w.p.1 there will be infinitely many integers $t$ such that $E_t$ occurs. Or, alternatively, let $E_t$ be independent with $P(E_t)=e^{-t}$. Then the integral is finite, but for any $0<a<b<1$ there are _uncountably_ many events $E_t$ with probability in $(a,b)$.

Comment: (but let's not pursue more iterations of the question -- at least, this is not the right place to do it.)

Comment: What does "i.o." mean?

Comment: @LSpice Good question. i.o. means infinitely often. I'll edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: Which actually raises another issue with this question: given an uncountable family of events $E_t$, the set $\{E_t \text{ i.o.}\}$ need not be measurable, so without more assumptions it does not even make sense to talk about its probability.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's a very good point that I didn't consider. I would also be happy to look into this in order to improve the question. I found this: https://www.emis.de/journals/GMJ/vol6/v6n3-1.pdf Might you have other references in mind?

Comment: Not offhand.  Frankly, I think this question illustrates a general principle in probability theory that no good ever comes of considering an uncountable family of independent events.  For that matter, if you think about it "right", no good ever comes of really considering uncountable families of events; in contexts like continuous-time stochastic processes when you think you want to do this, you want assumptions like cadlag that mean you can learn everything by studying countable families.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you for the additional comment. Measure theory was one of my favourite courses as an undergrad but I only took one course. These types of pathological cases weren't considered. Might there be particular books which develop this "right" perspective? Eager to learn more.

Comment: I don't know a book that studies this issue explicitly and in depth, but you see examples of the phenomenon in many places.  For instance, I like the construction of Brownian motion in Durrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples*, which really only constructs it at a countable dense set of times, and shows that it is *uniformly* continuous on this set.  Other books try to really construct an uncountable family of random variables and end up with awkward steps involving "modifications" of the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second Borel-Cantelli lemma has the additional condition that the events are *mutually independent*. This requirement becomes problematic for an  uncountable  index set. For example, suppose that $\{E_t\}_{0\le t\le 1}$ is a collection of mutally independent events such that $(\omega,t)\mapsto 1_{E_t}(\omega)$ is measurable. (This is needed for the integrations you envision.) Then 
$$
\int_a^b 1_{E_t}\,dt =\int_a^bp(t)\,dt,\qquad a.s.,
$$
where $p(t):=P(E_t)$. (To see this compute the variance of $\int_a^b 1_{E_t}\,dt$.) From this and the Lebesgue density and differentiation theorems it follows that $P(E_t)$ is $0$ or $1$ for a.e. $t$. Thus mutual independence and measurability hold only in trivial situations.